# invoke javascript function when scraping the web page

Tags: python

I am scraping a web page using python, the page has:

```
<input name="Submit" type="button" class="btn" value="query"  onclick = "dataQuery();" />
```

I want to trigger the onclick event in python, how can I do that, thanks

Comment: Find out what `dataQuery()` runs. It has to send a request somewhere. Just recreate that request with Python.

Comment: @Erik: Read the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings) and/or [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to control/simulate a web browser.

Note that if you just want to scrape a specific site, it's often easier to just recreate the JavaScript logic in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

For scraping web-pages you might be interested in [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

For submitting a form you can use [FormRequest.from_response](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response):

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'my_spider_name'
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/']
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
    advertiser = 'domain.com'


    def parse(self, response):
        """Parse first page and submit a form on it"""
        ...
        formdata = {'input1': '1234', 'input2': 5678} # overriden form data
        yield = FormRequest.from_response(response, 'form_name', formdata = formdata, 
                callback = self.parseFormSubmit)
```

For more info see the [scrapy docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/) and search on this site questions tagged with `scrapy`.